# How to use UIDocumentPickerViewController inside a ContainerView?

Tags: swift, ios17, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am displaying a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` inside a containerView so user can pick document while being able to interact with other controls on the screen. It works and the `documentPickerWasCancelled` delegate does kick in when user taps cancel button. But when user selects a file and taps Open, the `didPickDocumentsAt` delegate method does not fire.

If I present the picker using `present(pickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` then `didPickDocumentsAt` fires fine.

**How can I make it work inside a Container?**

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
...
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.item], asCopy: true)
    pickerViewController.delegate = self
    self.addChild(pickerViewController)
    self.containerView.addSubview(pickerViewController.view)
    pickerViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
    pickerViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        print("cancelled") // <- Works
    }
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        print("picked") // <- Does not work when inside ContainerView
...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. UIDocumentPickerViewController is designed to be displayed as a modal presentation. It calls the delegate method after it dismisses itself. Since, as a child, it can't dismiss itself, it doesn't call the `didPickDocumentsAt` delegate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by subclassing `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and overriding an internal `_callDelegateWithSelectedURLsAndDismiss:` method which works when the controller is presented modally only.

```swift
class DocumentPickerViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController {
  @objc
  func _callDelegateWithSelectedURLsAndDismiss(_ urls: [URL]) {
    delegate?.documentPicker?(self, didPickDocumentsAt: urls)
  }
}
```

Now the following code works for picking files:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet private var containerView: UIView!
  
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let pickerViewController = DocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.item], asCopy: true)
    pickerViewController.delegate = self
    self.addChild(pickerViewController)
    self.containerView.addSubview(pickerViewController.view)
    pickerViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
  }
}

extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
  func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    print(#function) // <- Works
  }
  
  func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    print(#function) // <- Works
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice hack. The question now is will Apple accept an app that uses that private API? And of course there's the possibility that such code could stop working with any iOS update.

Comment: That is very cool! I implemented it already. Only small caveat I cant figure out is why initially the picker is not adopting the app's AccentColor as its tint color. If the app shows an alert and then dismissed it, the picker starts showing the correct tint color then.

Comment: @Kashif When the time comes, please report the result of submitting your app to the App Store with this code. It would be good to know if this is something Apple will accept or not.

Comment: @HangarRash yes it was approved by apple